# React Native access this.state.key from another state key

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with state key that I want to set it only if other states have the value of X.

```
this.state = {
  //display items
  setLanguage:'eng',
  language:this.state.setLanguage=='eng'?Language.eng:Language.heb,
```

If I set the language to this.state I get the all state **keys** and **values**, but if I try to set it to

```
language:this.state.setLanguage
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this.state.setLanguage')

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a state that has not been set. The correct code should be:

```
this.state = {
    setLanguage,
    language: setLanguage === 'eng' ? Language.eng : Language.heb
}
```

There's another way, that is to set the new state using a callback.

```
this.setState({ setLanguage }, () => { this.setState({ language: this.state.setLanguage === 'eng' ? Language.eng : Language.heb }); });
```

Note that `this.state.setLanguage` is available inside the callback because the state has been already set in the first call.